# Can't enable an addon

Tags: add-on, installation

I have installed an addon [Space engineers modding addon](http://harag-on-steam.github.io/se-blender/#main-model), but cannot check the box to enable it. I get this error on the console:

```
fake_module: addon missing 'bl_info' gives bad performance!: 'C:\\Users\\Besitzer\\AppData\\Roaming\\Blender Foundation\\Blender\\2.66\\scripts\\addons\\install.py'
Error reading file as UTF-8: C:\Users\Besitzer\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.66\scripts\addons\release_scripts_wings_import.py 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc4 in position 26: invalid continuation byte
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Programme\blender-2.66a-windows64\2.66\scripts\modules\addon_utils.py", line 269, in enable
    mod = __import__(module_name)
  File "C:\Users\Besitzer\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.66\scripts\addons\space_engineers\__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    if not reload('utils'): from . import utils
  File "C:\Users\Besitzer\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.66\scripts\addons\space_engineers\__init__.py", line 20, in reload
    importlib.reload(modules[module_name])
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'reload'
```

this part of the error message appears multible times in the console:

```
fake_module: addon missing 'bl_info' gives bad performance!: 'C:\\Users\\Besitzer\\AppData\\Roaming\\Blender Foundation\\Blender\\2.66\\scripts\\addons\\install.py'
Error reading file as UTF-8: C:\Users\Besitzer\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.66\scripts\addons\release_scripts_wings_import.py 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc4 in position 26: invalid continuation byte
```

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your Console log, it seems pretty obvious that you are using Blender 2.66. The addon (as stated on the SE Block Tools homepage) needs Blender 2.75 or later.

Comment: now i can enable this addon. but where to find the toolkit in the work-area?

Comment: off topic how z´to make a new line in this comments here? if i try it as normal with "enter", it closes and saves the comment...

Answer (score 0):

Blender 2.7xxx **DOWNLOAD** [havok2013.1-fbx2015.1](https://github.com/harag-on-steam/fbximporter/releases/download/havok2013.1-fbx2015.1/fbximporter-havok2013.1-fbx2015.1.zip)
@harag-on-steam harag-on-steam released this on 23 Jan 2015

built against Havok SDK 2013.1
built against Autodesk FBX SDK 2015.1
fixes a null-reference when there are no anim-stacks
allows to specify an output-filename